# Getting Parent and Child data (Tree Checkbox) with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get all parent and child data from a database with Laravel. There will be nested parent and child within a parent as well. It's like a multi level kind of thing. The problem I'm facing is getting all those info using a loop. Below is my code.

```
$totalchild = self::getParentChildren($parent->id);

public function getParentChildren($parent) {
    $totalChild = array();
    $child = Permission::where('status', 1)->where('parentid', '=', $parent)->pluck('permissionid')->toArray();
    $totalChild = $child;
    foreach($child as $childs){
        $innerChild[] = self::getChildren($childs);
        $totalChild = array_push($totalChild, $innerChild);
    }

    return $totalChild;
}
```

The error I get is "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given". I've no idea what went wrong in there. Basically I'm trying to get all parents ID and child ID under this one parent ID. Thanks!

EDIT: Database example like below.

```
id    name        parentid
1     master      0
2     parent A    1          
3     parent B    1
4     child A     2
5     child B     2
6     child C     3
7     child A_A   4
8     child A_B   4
```

so lets say I want to get all parents and child under this master parent id 1.

CODE UPDATE:
I've came up another one but I don't know why it only returns me the first layer. It didn't return me all the parents and childs below it.

```
public function getChildren($parent, $tree_string=array()) {
    $tree = array();
    $tree = Permission::where('status', 1)->where('parentid', $parent)->pluck('permissionid')->toArray();
    if(count($tree)>0 && is_array($tree)){
        $tree_string=array_merge($tree_string,$tree);
    }
    foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
        self::getChildren($value, $tree_string);
    }
    return $tree_string;
}

$totalchild = self::getChildren($parent->id); // returns me the first layer only
```

Comment: Please share DB structure and some sample data.

Comment: added database, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by modifying the function... hope it's useful for other people.

```
public function getChildren($parent) {
    $tree = Array();
    if (!empty($parent)) {
        $tree = Permission::where('status', 1)->where('parentid', $parent)->pluck('permissionid')->toArray();
        foreach ($tree as $key => $val) {
            $ids = self::getChildren($val);
            if(!empty($ids)){
                if(count($ids)>0) $tree = array_merge($tree, $ids);
            }
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can define parent child relationship n `Eloquent` model.

```
// app/Category.php
class Category extends Model
{
    ...
    // Define Eloquent parent child relationship
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    // for first level child this will works enough
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    // and here is the trick for nestable child. 
    public static function nestable($categories) {
       foreach ($categories as $category) {
           if (!$category->children->isEmpty()) {
               $category->children = self::nestable($category->children);
            }
        }

        return $categories;
    }
    ...
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Get all parent top level category
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', 0);

// Get nestable data
$nestable = Category::nestable($categories);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well implementation for laravel

Comment: Is it possible to return all id in an array ?

Comment: Of course you can do it with same loop. But not sure what kind of array structure that you want. Since if it just contains `id`, how it will nested. Can you give your array output example?

Comment: i dont know why, but your code doesnt works for me, probably, im doing everything inside my controller. But i tried modifying but it doesn't helps.. Maybe help me look at my new code? I'm so close getting all the data, but it only returns me the first layer... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function allParent($child) {
        $tree = [];
        
        while($child) {
            array_push($tree, $child);
            $child = $child->parent;
        }
        return $tree;
}
```

you can give your $model->parent as the $this->allParent($model->parent)